# How to add a sheet in Google Sheets using API?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have to add a sheet via API. I am using [sheet.best API](https://sheet.best/). It works fine: I can add a sheet, but I don't know how to add sheet1, sheet2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function addsheet() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({ requests: [{ addSheet: { properties: { index: 1, title: "myBullSheet" } } }] }, "Spreadsheet id");
}
```

[Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)

Don't forget to enable Sheets API